# How to show dynamic info from array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

```
let nofificationsarray = [{message:"Contract GGK011SH0001C need approval in the system", notificationDate:"2018-06-05 06:23:48", profileFileId:"", "username: siva"},
{message:"Contract GGK011SH0002C need approval in the system", notificationDate:"2018-07-05 06:23:48", profileFileId:"", "username: siva"},
{message:"Contract GGK011SH0003C need approval in the system", notificationDate:"2018-08-05 06:23:48", profileFileId:"", "username: siva"},
{message:"Contract GGK011SH0003C need approval in the system", notificationDate:"2018-09-05 06:23:48", profileFileId:"", "username: siva"}
]
```

In this notificationsarray variable i am having array information of all the notifications.
based on the array fields i want to populate all the notifications dynamically.

I am trying to use map of array and trying to populate but i am not able to get anything

```
const allnotifications = notificationsarray && notificationsarray.map((value, key) => {
        return <li className="notification_block">
        <div className="notification_profile_img">
        <img src={value.profileFileId} className="profile_img"/>
        </div>
        <div className="notification_profile_txt">
          <h4> {value.username}</h4>
          <p> {value.message} </p>
          <p><small>{value.notificationDate}</small></p>
        </div>
      </li>
          });
```

I want this `<li>` tag to be looped based on the length of the notifications array In this case i have 3 objects in the array I want this `<li>` Tag to come for 3 times

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What you are doing is correct. What's your error? That map should work (if I'm not missing any code syntax error).

Comment: It need to loop  for 3 times according to the array but i am getting undefined. if i console allnotifications.

Comment: How is notificationsarray getting populated

Comment: Your notificationarray data is wrong "username: siva"

Answer (score 0):

well you have some syntax mistakes - like spelling of nofificationsarray, error in username siva. Otherwise, your solution is correct.

https://codepen.io/smilesaayush/pen/rKMGJV

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
  }
  render() {
    let nofificationsarray = [{message:"Contract GGK011SH0001C need approval in the system", notificationDate:"2018-06-05 06:23:48", profileFileId:"", username: "siva"},
{message:"Contract GGK011SH0002C need approval in the system", notificationDate:"2018-07-05 06:23:48", profileFileId:"", username: "siva"},
{message:"Contract GGK011SH0003C need approval in the system", notificationDate:"2018-08-05 06:23:48", profileFileId:"", username: "siva"},
{message:"Contract GGK011SH0003C need approval in the system", notificationDate:"2018-09-05 06:23:48", profileFileId:"", username: "siva"}
];
    return (
      <div>
         {
          nofificationsarray.map((value, key) => {
            return (
              <li className="notification_block">
                <div className="notification_profile_img">
                <img src={value.profileFileId} className="profile_img"/>
                </div>
                <div className="notification_profile_txt">
                  <h4> {value.username}</h4>
                  <p> {value.message} </p>
                  <p><small>{value.notificationDate}</small></p>
                </div>
              </li>
            )

          })
        }
      </div>
    )

  }
}
```